# Laravel Inertia scaffolding but with vue2

Tags: laravel, vuejs2, inertiajs

The laravel starter kit install inertia with authorizations components in vue3.
I must use vue2 because other reasons.
Is there anyone who has been able to configure it using vue2

- uninstall vue3 and install vue2
- uninstall inertia for vue3 and install the regular(compatible with vue2)

Answer (score 0):

you need to install an older version for Jetstream, edit composer.json and change

```
"laravel/jetstream": "2.1.4"
```

And finally

```
npm install; npm run dev; php artisan migrate
```